# WebView - view 2 web's

Tags: android, webview

I have this code:

```
package butterfly.menu;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MenuActivity extends Activity {
   WebView mWebView;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        if (savedInstanceState != null)
            ((WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview)).restoreState(savedInstanceState);

        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 
        mWebView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false); 

        mWebView.loadUrl("http://myweb.pl/web2");
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new MenuClient());
    }
    private class MenuClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    }
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
       mWebView.saveState(outState);
     }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME || keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK || keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN || keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP || keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_CALL || keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_POWER || keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_CAMERA || keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_CLEAR || keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER || keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_POWER)) {
            //mWebView.goBack();
            return false;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

}
```

This code work 100% correct. I need make this:
a) if my phone is in position horizontal - then load: http://myweb.pl/web2/index1.html
b) if my phone is in position vertical- then load: http://myweb.pl/web2/index2.html

Who know what i must to do?

Thank's for help

---

it's not doing :(

I have this:

```
package butterfly.menu;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

    public class MenuActivity extends Activity {
        WebView mWebView;
        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
            if (savedInstanceState != null)
                ((WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview)).restoreState(savedInstanceState);

            mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
            mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); // włączenie JS
            mWebView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false); // blokada ZOOMu

            mWebView.loadUrl("http://topvesta.home.pl/tablety"); // strona do wyświetlenia
            mWebView.setWebViewClient(new MenuClient());
            if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)
            {
                mWebView.loadUrl(" http://www.interia.pl");
            }

            else if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
            {
                mWebView.loadUrl("http://wp.pl");
            }
        }
        private class MenuClient extends WebViewClient {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }
        }
        protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
            mWebView.saveState(outState);
         }

        @Override
        public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME || keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK || keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN || keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP || keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_CALL || keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_POWER || keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_CAMERA || keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_CLEAR || keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER || keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_POWER)) {
                //mWebView.goBack();
                return false;
            }
            return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
        }

    }
```

I have always onet.pl - newer wp.pl :(

Comment: Copying code without understand what it is being done is a recipe for disaster.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamically load load the WebView based on the device orientation using

```
    if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)
    {
        mWebView.loadUrl(" http://myweb.pl/web2/index2.html");
    }

    else if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
    {
        mWebView.loadUrl(" http://myweb.pl/web2/index1.html");
    }
```